# Aligning the Left Hand Side of a big equation with fraction

Tags: vertical-alignment, fractions

After spending quite some time making sure this wasn't already answered, I decided to post this anyway, as I haven't found what I'm looking for.

I have this equation with nested fractions, and I want the Left Hand Side to be centered with respect to the Right Hand Side.
It now appears at the hard left corner, I want it to be in the middle. See the picture below for an example.

```
\documentclass[]{Article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath} 
\begin{document}

\begin{math}

\ C(m) =  \cfrac{D_1(K_1+mK_2)}{1- \cfrac{1}{ \left(  \cfrac{D_1+D_2}{D_2} \right) ^{m+1}- \cfrac{D_1}{D_2}}}
\end{math}

\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 2):

I would advise against this, since the display seems confusion. The fractional content is aligned, vertically, to the outer `\frac`'s math axis, which is located at the horizontal rule. However, you can fake a fraction using an `array`, that has a vertically centered math axis regardless of the location of the horizontal rule:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}

\[
  C(m) = \cfrac{D_1(K_1 + mK_2)}
    {1 - \cfrac{1}
      { \left( \cfrac{D_1 + D_2}{D_2} \right)^{m+1} - \cfrac{D_1}{D_2}}}
\]

\[
  C(m) = \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    D_1(K_1 + mK_2) \\ \hline
    1- \dfrac{\strut 1}
      { \biggl( \dfrac{D_1 + D_2}{D_2} \biggr)^{m+1} - \dfrac{D_1}{D_2}}
    \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

There didn't seem to be a need for using the `c`ontinued `frac`tions.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Your code looks really neat.
I suppose the position of the LHS is a matter of taste. I might reconsider repositioning it. And, I have yet to delve into the subtleties of dfrac/cfrac.

Comment: @MisterMister: All the subtleties are described in the [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) [user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf) (section **4.11 Fractions and related constructions**, p 14).